# Particle js hiding web elements below it

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I am using particle js as a background image.Now

```
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
 <div class="text">
    <h1>Particles Background</h1>
 </div>
```

I have to set position attribute of `.text` as `absolute`. Otherwise the section remains hidden. I don't seem to understand why others become hidden. I can't use `absolute` as it will break my code. Below is the css. Only if I set `.text` as `position:absolute` it will display

```css
#particles-js {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<div class="text">
  <h1>Particles Background</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also set `position:absolute;` for `#particle-js`

Comment: use z-index also

Comment: what is the deal with position...I donot understand it.Can somebody explain

Comment: @RajanBenipuri .

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue possibly because of heighr `z-index` value for `#particle-js`

You can do it by either making `position: absolute;` for `#particle-js` and/or increasing the `z-index` for `.text`

To understand more about positions [please check this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are using divs which by default have layout but with no contents have no size.  You also position the right of one element so the text is off screen.  You can then fix that by right align of the text in the div.  Here I put two examples to help understand the differences, one with no content as you have and one with a right aligned text.

I put some borders on just so you have a visual of the elements.

```css
#mycontainer{border:solid lime 1px;}

#particles-js {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mycontainer">
  <div id="particles-js">cheese&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Particles Background</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second example

```css
#mycontainer {
  border: solid lime 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#particles-js {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border: solid 1px red;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="mycontainer">
  <div id="particles-js">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Particles Background</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```